# Not able to create hive table using sqoop

Tags: hive, sqoop, hadoop3

I am trying below command to import the mysql table `stocks` to my hive(v3.1.2) in Ubuntu 18.0.4 and Hadoop 3 using sqoop(v1.4.7)

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/myhadoop --username hiveuser --password xxx --table stocks --bindir /usr/local/sqoop/lib/ --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --target-dir /user/hduser/stocks6 -m 1 --hive-import --hive-table d1.stocks
```

But the table stocks has not been created in hive database `d1`.
Please advise.
Log:

```
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2360: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_USER: bad substitution
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2455: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_OPTS: bad substitution
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2360: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_USER: bad substitution
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2455: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_OPTS: bad substitution
Fri May 15 16:53:55 IST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Note: /usr/local/sqoop/lib/stocks.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Fri May 15 16:54:04 IST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri May 15 16:54:06 IST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri May 15 16:54:08 IST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a hive table as part of sqoop-import, you need to add `--create-hive-table` 
[Note: *the job will fail if the target hive table exists*]

Found one [article](https://dzone.com/articles/sqoop-import-data-from-mysql-to-hive) and [documentation of sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive)